# Disable iAds on Different Scene Cocos2d 3.0

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, iad

I finally have iAds working, how would I make is so the ads dont show up on my game scene?

This is my iAds code

```
- (id)init
{
{
    if ([ADBannerView instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(initWithAdType:)]) {
        _adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithAdType:ADAdTypeBanner];

    } else {
        _adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] init];
    }
    _adView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait];
    _adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector]view]addSubview:_adView];
    [_adView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector]view]addSubview:_adView];
    _adView.delegate = self;
}
return self;
}
```

Comment: remove the adview when the game scene launches

Comment: What code would i use to remove it?

Comment: one of many options: [_adView removeFromSuperview]

Answer (score 0):

To stop the iAd from staying even though a scene has been changed add

```
[_adView removeFromSuperview]
```

To where the Scene is being changes so it look like this

```
- (void)onscoreButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
// start spinning scene with transition
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[HighScoreScene scene]
                           withTransition:[CCTransition transitionPushWithDirection:CCTransitionDirectionUp duration:1.0f]];
[_adView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Thank you to LearnCocos2d